# django templates - include another block from same folder

Tags: django, templates

I'm new to django, I'm trying to figure out how to include other html files from the same subfolder to my main template file.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
{% include './_shared.html' %}
```

I'll eventually have many template folders. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put your sub folders inside your template directory

You have to define your template path in your settings.py

now you can `include`   that template file like `{% include '/yoursubfolder/file.html' %}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% include request.path+"_shared.html" %}
```

You might have to add slash between path and file name.